# Extracting the last instance of specific data from x number of files using python

Tags: python, automation, scripting

I have a folder containing hundreds of files (scan_zmat_x.txt) where x is an incremental int [1,2,3...]. I need to open the file, find the last instance of a line, let's call it "gumballs" for now. Then I need to put everything in a new file. So far I've tried using .sh scripts but I only have access to a Windows machine currently. So py is a good alternative. I'm really stuck and could use some guidance.

I appreciate it. Cheers.

```
#!/bin/tcsh
Efile=opt/e.txt
Logs=opt/infiles/scan_zmat_$i.log
for i in Logs do
grep -winr "gumballs" scan_zmat_$i.log|tail -n 1 > $Efile
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to wait, just find each line with the value you want in each file, keeping the last one each time

```py
import glob

search_string = "gumballs"

with open("results.txt") as fh_results:
    for name_file in glob.iglob("scan_zmat_*.txt"):
        discovered_line = None  # clear the match for each file
        with open(name_file) as fh:
            for line in fh:
                if search_string in line:  # update on each match
                    discovered_line = line
    if discovered_line is not None:
        fh_results.write(line)  # includes newline chars
    # else:  # optional message
    #     print(f"WARNING: no lines in '{name_file}' matched '{search_string}'")
```

Caveats

- Both this and your original search may be sorted by the inode (or Windows/NTFS equivalent), which is *normally* the order the files were written in, but not necessarily
  If you want to be certain they're sorted, use `glob.glob` and sort it as you prefer instead of using `glob.iglob` directly (which yields an iterable of the filenames in the order provided by the filesystem)
- If the files are large, it could be more efficient to seek backwards in blocks (repeatedly `.seek()`ing)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested! If you don't want to wait)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from os.path import join as joinpath
from os import listdir  # like 'ls' in bash

# Path to files you want to read
DIRPATH = "/home/some/path/"
OUTFILE = "out.txt"  # will be created in cwd
collected = []  # OS dependent sorting

def main():
    for fname in listdir(DIRPATH):
        # Check with 'os.path.isfile' if you want
        if fname.startswith("scan_zmat_") and fname.endswith(".txt"):
            with open(joinpath(DIRPATH, fname), "rb") as fd:
                # GOTO second last byte
                fd.seek(-1, 2)
                # every read() advances the pointer
                while fd.read(1) == b"\n":
                    fd.seek(-2, 1)  
                end = fd.tell() + 1
                fd.seek(-1, 1)
                while fd.read(1) != b"\n":
                    fd.seek(-2, 1)

                collected.append(fd.read(end-fd.tell()))

    with open(OUTFILE, "wb") as fd:
        fd.writelines(collected)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: they'll sadly still have to wait! reading files like this is bound to be _much_ slower than reading it in blocks (of some multiple of their filesystem block size) and the Question is trying to find the last instance of a _specific line_ with some string in it, not the _last line_

Comment: Is there some 'quick read' for this problem? Is it really slower to jump to the end of file than to traverse it, is it not as the same as to jump to last element of an array? I have no knowledge of FS's but it sounds counterintuitive. Ty.